# Reshaping data with header data and body data

Tags: r, reshape

I am looking for an elegant R reshape routine/function to transform some sort of header (h.1 - h.3) and body (b1 - b4) data into a format that groups the body data below each header row.

So from this:

```
df.orig
   h.1 h.2 h.3  b1  b2  b3  b4
1   a1  b1  c1  r1  s1  t1  x1
2   a1  b1  c1  r1  s1  t1  x2 
3   a2  b2  c2  r2  s2  t2  z1
4   a2  b2  c2  r2  s2  t2  z2
 ....
```

to this:

```
df.reshaped 

   X.1  X.2  X.3  X.4
1   a1   b1   c1    
2   r1   s1   t1   x1
3   r1   s1   t1   x2 
4   a2   b2   c2 
5   r2   s2   t2   z1 
6   r2   s2   t2   z2 
  ....
```

Never mind the loss of of original header names on the way from `df.orig` to `df.reshape`.

Comment: You could manipulate further something like `split(df.orig[c("b1", "b2", "b3", "b4")], interaction(df.orig[c("h.1", "h.2", "h.3")], drop = T))`. But, even if you just keep the "list" from `split`, I guess it might be easier for subsequent analysis

Comment: thanks for the hint; my pain comes from the fact that it's not really subsequent analysis I am bothered with it's a pure formatting issue - a subsequent system needs that type of header body structure to allow uploading the data set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would that work for you? (assuming `temp` is your data set)

```
f <- function(x, y) rbind(as.character(x), as.character(y))
temp2 <- data.frame(unique(mapply(f, cbind(temp[, names(temp)[grepl("h", names(temp))]], NA), temp[, names(temp)[grepl("b", names(temp))]])))
names(temp2) <- paste0("X.", seq_len(4))

  X.1 X.2 X.3  X.4
1  a1  b1  c1 <NA>
2  r1  s1  t1   x1
3  r1  s1  t1   x2
4  a2  b2  c2 <NA>
5  r2  s2  t2   z1
6  r2  s2  t2   z2
```

Comment: looks interesting 
will give it a shot with my original (much larger) data set; 
if I can get it to work there - I will of course upvote the answer 
Thanks ...

Comment: Does issue a warning ... "In mapply(FUN = f, x = cbind( : .... longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter", but produces an output I can easily alter for my needs from there on ... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like the following. This depends on having unique values in the body columns (which can easily be added using an indicator variable of some sort if they are not presently unique).

The basic concept is to create a column of `NA` as the fourth column (since that's how many columns we want in the end), and re-make a matrix with the values ordered how we want them.

```
mydf <- cbind(mydf[1:3], h.4 = NA, mydf[4:7])
temp <- matrix(c(t(mydf)), ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)
unique(temp)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,] "a1" "b1" "c1" NA  
# [2,] "r1" "s1" "t1" "x1"
# [3,] "r1" "s1" "t1" "x2"
# [4,] "a2" "b2" "c2" NA  
# [5,] "r2" "s2" "t2" "z1"
# [6,] "r2" "s2" "t2" "z2"
```

---

If that approach works, you could also look at `interleave` from "gdata":

```
library(gdata)
unique(interleave(setNames(cbind(mydf[1:3], NA), 1:4), 
                  setNames(mydf[4:7], 1:4)))
#     1  2  3    4
# 1  a1 b1 c1 <NA>
# 11 r1 s1 t1   x1
# 21 r1 s1 t1   x2
# 3  a2 b2 c2 <NA>
# 31 r2 s2 t2   z1
# 41 r2 s2 t2   z2
```

Comment: that "interleave" function looks extremely useful in that context; wasn't aware of it; thanks a lot for that pointer